# Passar parâmetro para componente da Tab.Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Como passar parâmetros para o componente da Tab Screen?

Ficha/index.js:

```
import Historico from './Historico';

export default function Ficha({ route, navigation }) {

  const { periodo } = route.params; // quero passar o periodo para o Historico

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({})}
        tabBarOptions={...}
    >

    <Tab.Screen
      name="Historico"
      component={Historico}
      options={{
        title: 'Histórico',
        tabBarOptions: {
          tabStyle: {
            width: 'auto',
          },
        },
      }}
    />

    ...

   </Tab.Navigator>

 );
```

Historico/index.js:

```
export default function Historico({ navigation }) {
  // acessar aqui, de alguma forma, o "periodo" passado na Tab Screen.
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Izi pizi

```
export default function Historico({ navigation, route }) {
  ...
  console.log(route.params); //provavelmente o valor ja vai estar 
                            // aqui, se nao estiver voce segue o exemplo abaixo tambem
}
```

---

```
  <Tab.Screen
      name="Historico"
      component={Historico}
      initialParams={{ periodo }} <----
      options={{
        title: 'Histórico',
        tabBarOptions: {
          tabStyle: {
            width: 'auto',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
```